# How do we communicate with the root component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the root component, i put a modal that can be triggered from anywhere. But, I actually confuse how does the bottom component can communicate to the top without passing too much callback function?

Root Component

```
<container></container>
<modal hide="true"></modal>
```

Container Component

```
<another-container></another-container>
```

Another Container Component

```
<child-that-trigger-modal></child-that-trigger-modal>
```

Basically, I want the bottom component (child-that-trigger-modal) can communicate with the top component that has modal (root) in a simple and elegant way without passing too much data and callback function?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2, events emitted by `EventEmmiter` don't bubble (*as of date of posting this answer*).

You could use a shared service that will help you to communicate between your components.

```
// File: app/shared.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  notify$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  notify(obj) {
      this.notify$.next(obj);
  }

}
```

Now, you have created `Observable` and shared service (note that single instance of it will be shared across your components).

If you want to send data , you can use `.notify()` function, e.g.

```
export class ChildThatTriggerModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  notifyParent() {
      this.sharedService.notify({id: 1, name: 'John'});
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

If you want to listen for any changes, you can `subscribe` to that observable, e.g.

```
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.sharedService.notify$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Comment: i dont use subject actually, but thanks anw, it helps

Comment: Glad to hear. You can accept the answer if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest, is to not tie the modal to root component.
Instead your modal should be a service (that may or may not require root component as a dependency)

And then

1. Inject the modal service into root component, if you need/want to.
2. Inject the same instance into your child that triggers it (just make sure it's singleton, i.e. declared only once, in your app.module for example)